# Extracting a value from a key/value pair stored in a text field

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I need to extract the value from a key/value pair stored in a text field using sql in oracle 11g.

I can detect the "key" with

```
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE valuet2 LIKE '%' || chr(10) || 'F;' || '%'
```

but I'm not confidant this is the best way to do the search, and I don't know how to return the value of variable length (up to, but not including the carriage return).

This is the text field I need to search against and extract the value from.

```
;Please Select;*
E;Expelled
F;Expelled Following Suspension
N;In-School Suspension
S;Out-of-School Suspension
BS;Bus Suspension
101;Detention
130;Conference / Warning
131;Parent Contact / Conference
200;Loss of Recess
```

I'm querying a separate table that stores the "key", so I need to do the lookup from this text field to determine what that key value represents. I will be pushing this query out to other servers that will have their own unique combinations of key/value pairs, and I cannot anticipate what those may be. Therefore, I cannot write a decode.

Comment: you would select the variable length up to but not including the carriage return by doing:      select substr(fieldname,1,instr(fieldname,(chr(10))))
        from my_table;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression functions and take advantage of the `'m'` modifier, which instructs Oracle to treat `^` and `$` as the start-of-line and end-of-line anchors (rather than matching only at the beginning and the end of the string). Something like this:

```
select regexp_substr(valuet2, '^F;(.*)$', 1, 1, 'm', 1)
from   mytable
where  regexp_like(valuet2, '^F;', 'm')
;
```

Brief demo:

```
create table mytable (valuet2 varchar2(4000));

insert into mytable(valuet2) values(
';Please Select;*
E;Expelled
F;Expelled Following Suspension
N;In-School Suspension
S;Out-of-School Suspension
BS;Bus Suspension
101;Detention
130;Conference / Warning
131;Parent Contact / Conference
200;Loss of Recess'
);

select regexp_substr(valuet2, '^F;(.*)$', 1, 1, 'm', 1) as myval
from   mytable
where  regexp_like(valuet2, '^F;', 'm')
;

MYVAL                                   
----------------------------------------
Expelled Following Suspension
```

Here `F` is hardcoded, but you can replace it with a bind variable; the query needs to be tweaked slightly. Please write back if you need help with that.

Comment: Perfect solution! Exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My not 100% sure what you are looking for but

select  substr(valuet2,length(:val)+2)  FROM mytable
    WHERE valuet2 LIKE  :val || ';%';

will work to get everything after the ; where the before matches :val

Comment: This will get everything after `F;` - including all the following lines of text. Note that the OP references `chr(10)` explicitly, which suggests the example text given in the question is a **single** value, not several values (from separate rows) in the base table.